# Databricks/ ADF / Azure functions for excel file processing

Tags: azure, function, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have few excel files that needs to be processed..either send them to an on premise sql database or output csv files which are more structured.
The files can run into 100MB and have multiple sheets. The sheets and data are dynamic. Some files may or may not get some sheets. The columns are also the same.
Plus point is, each file has a data dictionary sheet that explains the structure (Sheets and the corresponding columns)

This for sure cannot be just handled by a simple copy activity in ADF alone. I have written a scala code within databricks that handles most of the processing.

I'm thinking of using ADF to orchestrate the flow along with Databricks.

I also have Azure function app in mind instead of databricks.

I'm new to the whole Azure domain. I want to see what is the optimal way in terms of cost and performance to handle this situation.

Also can this be handled using a data flow activity in ADF? I tried but ended up running into a lot of limitations there as well in terms of using an in premise database and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches which you can try. One is using **Mapping Data Flow** in ADF and other is you can run Databricks Notebook using **Databricks Notebook activity** in ADF.

> Mapping data flows are visually designed data transformations in Azure
> Data Factory. Data flows allow data engineers to develop data
> transformation logic **without writing code**. The resulting data flows
> are executed as activities within Azure Data Factory pipelines that
> use scaled-out Apache Spark clusters.

Even when the database is on-premises, you can easily access the data by using **Self hosted Integration Runtime**. Refer this third-party tutorial to know [how to deploy Self-hosted IR in ADF](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5812/connect-to-onpremises-data-in-azure-data-factory-with-the-selfhosted-integration-runtime-part-1/) and use it to connect with on-premises SQL Server. You can also refer this [alternative approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server) for the same by using private endpoint.
Once done, you can use the database in **Data Flow activity**.

Now, second option is using **Databricks Notebook activity** in ADF pipeline. This is same as running Databricks job but here you will trigger it using ADF.

> Azure Data Factory pipeline executes a Databricks notebook against the
> Databricks jobs cluster. It also passes Azure Data Factory parameters
> to the Databricks notebook during execution.

You can trigger these pipeline using schedule or event based trigger to make it completely automated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I personally prefer a code first approach. How about the difference in cost? Since both are running on a spark cluster, is it safe to say, both are same?

Comment: Since user has more control in Databricks and you need to write your own code, Databricks is quite cheap compare to Synapse.

```Databricks has a ‘Lake House’ architecture that leverages data lake and data warehouse elements to provide low-cost data management. This architecture facilitates ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Durability).```